show that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_E|f_k(x)-f(x)|dx=0$
Let $f_k$ be a sequence of nonnegative Lebesgue integrable functions defined on $E\subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $f\in L_1(E)$ so that $f_k\to f$ converges in measure as $k\to\infty$. If $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_E f_k(x)dx=\int_E f(x)dx$$, show that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_E|f_k(x)-f(x)|dx=0$$

I read the solution but I am confused about one step.
We define $g_k(x):=f_k(x)-f(x)$. Then
$$
g_k^+-g_k^-=g_k\to^{\mu} f-f=0
$$
(converges in measure as $k\to\infty$).
Clearly, we have $0\le f-g_k^-=f_k-g_k^+\le f$.
By Dominated convergence theorem,
$$
\int_E f-\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_E g_k^-=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_E(f-g_k^-)=\int_E f
$$
Question: how to get the second equality? That means $\lim_{k\to\infty}(f-g_k^-)=f$.
If this one holds, then we get $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_Eg_k^-=0$. Moreover, we can get
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_Eg_k^+=0
$$

$g_k \to 0$ in measure and this  implies $g_k^{-} \to 0$ in measure.

@geetha290krm But this is convergence in measure. Why should this one implies $g_k^-\to 0$ in this integral? $\int_E g^-_k\to 0$?

DCT holds for convergence in measure also.

@geetha290krm Oh! I forgot it. Thank you!
